# IntelliJ - Unresolved JavaScript Reference

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, lint

I'm writing Javascript on IntelliJ with some env variable use, ex.

```
const DEBUG = process && process.env.COMMAND_DEBUG === 'true';
```

But the IDE told me `Unresolved variable or type process`.

So I tried to switch to this form

```
import { env } from 'node:process';
const DEBUG = env.COMMAND_DEBUG === 'true';
```

But I've always a warn on this subject (cf. image).

I'm new to IntelliJ Ultimate version 2023.1.2 with NodeJs
and it seems that JavaScript comes with some bundled plugins like `JavaScript and TypeScript plugin` (we dont have it in IntelliJ Community Edition).

Do you know how could I switch off this warn only for this use case (cause it could be usefull in other case) ?

[image: inspection profile JSandTS plugin]
[image: Unresolved JavaScript Reference]

Comment: Have you enabled Node.js assistance for the project?

Comment: hey Sergey, you re right, that fixed it ! thanks !!  I let you create a regular answer I will push it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Intellij IDEs by default you are working in a "browser" environment. For Node.js specific completions and analysis you have to enable it for the project in the settings.

Comment: settings > search "nodejs coding assistance" : check it